# Google Latitude API and iOS not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-latitude

I am using latitude API to make an iphone app which is similar to the latitude app for iOS.
For authentication i am doing the steps told in the latitude api documentation and sending the url after getting the oAuth. 
 https://www.google.com/latitude/apps/OAuthAuthorizeToken?domain=%3Cmy%20domain%3Elocation=current&granularity=best&oauth_token=%3Coauth%20t.

The posting of the location is working fine but only for the users which I have switched ON the access.
I found out that the url for showing the user option of sharing his location with friends is https://latitude.google.com/latitude/b/0 but on opening the link in webview,it is being redirected to itunes with latitude app for iOS instead of showing the dialog asking user to permit access his sharing of location to his friends.
What is the correct way of asking for user's permission.Please help if someone has faced same issue and has solved it for iOS.I am badly stuck up and has been looking in it for weeks but no avail.

Thanks in Advance